# BFS and DFS on a undirected and unweighed Graph in Java

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

```
public class Graph {
 private int V; //Number of vertices
    private int E; // Number of edges
    private ArrayList<Integer>[] adj; 

 public void addEdge(int v, int w) {
        if (!this.adj[v].contains(w)) {
            this.adj[v].add(w);
        }

        if (!this.adj[w].contains(v)) {
            this.adj[w].add(v);
        }
    }
public Graph bfs(int s) {

    }
public Graph dfs(int s) {

    }
```

I have created Graph in java such that an array of ArrayList holds the vertices attached to another vertices. I want to Implement BFS and DFS on this structure of Graph such that that I get a DFS/BFS graph from a single source. Any suggestions/guidelines.

Comment: You can customize [this](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~dmarino/ucf/java/DFS_BFS.java) to suit your requirements.

Comment: _"such that that I get it get object of the same class back"_ ? Also, did you check out wikipedia? They've got all you need.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ I did it on trees in past but stuck on graphs, edited the mistake in OP.

Comment: @wali There difference is that you go to neighbours instead of children, i.e. not much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Re-implement this in an OOP-with-GC way - each node should have a set of nodes it has edges to. Then this problem becomes quite easy. You iterate the adjacent nodes of the start node. For DFS, you recurse on each node. For BFS, you put the nodes in a Deque, and always get the Deque's tail.

Comment: What about the flow using this structure?

Comment: Write a method:
Set<V> getAdjacent( Graph g, int vertexId )
And take it from there. For DFS you recurse, for BFS you queue.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the red-black tree to get in-order traversal of graph, once you get traversal use Math.random() to replace all existing values with new ones. make sure you use SEED= Integer.max_value;